# Add QTextEdit objects to a QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qmainwindow

I seem to be having an issue.  Objective:  I want to dynamically add `QTextEdit` to a `QMainWindow`, I have a lot of data I wish to split amongst various `QTextEdit` objects.  I've been looking at `centralWidget` and did some digging into `ui->setupUi(this);` generated by the Qt Creator and spotted that the parent for objects of interest was the central widget of the `QMainWindow`.  Thus I've tried something like this:

```
this->m_vecTextEdits.push_back( new QTextEdit(this->centralWidget()) );
```

where '`this`' is the `QMainWindow`.  I just want to add these `QTextEdit` to the `QMainWindow` and later remove them.  I also tried `new QTextEdit(this)` hoping it would appear on the `QMainWindow` with the properties defined by the objects geometry to no luck.

If I `setCentralWidget` to be that of the `QTextEdit` than it works but I don't want the object to consume the entire `QMainWindow` and restrict access to existing widgets.

So I'm in need of advice of basically how I can add `QTextEdit` widgets to the existing `centralWidget` of the `QMainWindow` and have them appear in the window and also remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to add multiple QTextEdit so I can use a residing QListWidget
>   (the index property) to switch amongst the many QTextEdit widgets

You could put a `QStackedWidget` in place of your `QTextEdit`, and add all the `QTextEdit`s to it.

Only one of the textedits would be visible at all time, but you can switch between them automatically by connecting the signal `currentRowChanged(int)` of your `QListWidget` to the slot `setCurrentIndex(int)` so that the index of the `QTextEdit` stay the same as the index of the selected item in your list.

The `QStackedWidget` will replace your container m_vecTextEdits too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to just create the widget objects; you also need to add them to a layout object. Try something like:

```
QBoxLayout * bl = new QBoxLayout(centralWidget());
QTextEdit * t = new QTextEdit;
bl->addWidget(t);
```

Comment: Hi Mat, you are right.  A layout is needed, I have found three ways to do it.  Make a layout like you have suggested.  I also spotted the QMainWindow has a layout() const QLayout* also which I can pull to use addWidget through that AND the centralWidget ALSO has a layout() method thus possessing a addWidget method also.  I also see I can just pass a new central widget and qt's hierarchical tree will prune the prior objects.

Comment: At the moment: this->layout()->addWidget( this->m_vecTextEdits[uiIndex] );

Comment: and I can also use this->layout()->removeWidget(*ptr..) which is excellent, Qt really is a great framework.